# angular 5 run different thread in a background

Tags: multithreading, angular

I am using angular 5 with pouchdb. When I save a user I need to show it immediately in the users list. Meanwhile a background thread must geolocate the users city and update its coordinates for that user.

The geolocation calculation takes a second or two to load that is why I am thinking of running in a background thread.

I looked into [angular service worker](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-intro), But I think its for getting files for offline.

I also looked [angular cli web worker](https://github.com/kaikcreator/angular-cli-web-worker), But It did not mention how to call a background service and get a value back to main thread.

Is there a clear way to run a background thread in angular 5?

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by `But I think its for getting files for offline.`? can you add some more details?

Comment: Why don't you use an Observable to do the asynchronous task?

Comment: Yes I can use observable. But I wanted to try with some web worker kind of a thing.

Comment: @KarthickManoharan :  As I read partially about service workers. It is intended to serve content from cache and interpret with network. I was not able to find any example to serve as an alternate thread.

Comment: @Cristian, do you have an example of an Observable as an asynchronous task? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using [rxjs](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/) you can define and create an observable that do what you want :

```
    myObservable = Observable.create(function (observer) {
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => observer.next(position));
      }
    });
```

Then use it to get the desired value asynchronously :

```
myObservable.subscribe(pushedValue => console.log(pushedValue));
```

[Here is a running example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-49685268)

This is not real multithread (not needed in this case in my opinion), for that you need to look more to web workers.

Comment: Yes I can use with observable. But I wanted to try with alternate thread.

Comment: You could use this library to make a parallel js execution thread with angular : https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-web-worker
Not sure that its the right way of doing it because its made for heavy cpu functions, but you can give it a try and give us a feedback.

Answer (score 0):

For Aangular 5 or under, I am using setTimout()

```
 var _setTimeoutHandler = setTimout(() => {  myfunction(){}})
```

Make sure you clear variable _setTimeoutHandler before quit to avoid resource leaking 
I am also searching better way.